# Possibility that Sum of Random Variable Converges Weakly to Uniform Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, weak-convergence, uniform-distribution

Suppose $\{\xi_n\}$ are independent random variables such that $|\xi_n|\leq C$, $\forall n$. They also have densities $p_n(x)$, and $|p_n(x)|\leq C$, $\forall n,x$. Is it possible that $\sum\xi_n$ converge in distribution to a uniform distribution?

There is another similar question, on which I am equally clueless:

Suppose  $\{\xi_n\}$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, are there real numbers $\{a_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$ such that $0\leq |a_n|\leq 1$, $\forall n$, and
$$B_n+\sum_{k=1}^na_k\xi_k\to\zeta$$
weakly, $\zeta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$?

I feel like proof of weak convergence is usually done with characteristic functions, some form of central limit theorem, or direct computation of distribution functions. But none of these appears to work in these case. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: While the input data is about weak convergence, the weak convergence of a sum of independent random variables is in fact equivalent to the almost sure convergence of the sum

Comment: You must use the T.Lewis Theorem (1968 Journal of applied probability) which solves the Paul L\'evy conjecture about the factorization of the uniform distribution.